# Assign observable within callback in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am completely a newbie to Angular. Some how struggled to get the initial code working now I am stuck here.
Use case : Show loading bar. Fetch merchant list to an observable. Stop loading bar.

Problem:

```
fetchUsers($event) {
    let searchTerm = $event.term;
    if (searchTerm.length > 3) {
      this.isLoading=true;
      this.people$ = null;
      this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm);
  --> this.isLoading=false;
   }
}
```

this.isLoading becomes false even before getting the response from getMerchantsBySearch call. I know I will need to perform this step in callback but I am not sure how to.

I want to do something like this but I a missing something. What is the correct way to do it.

```
fetchUsers($event) {
    let searchTerm = $event.term;
    if (searchTerm.length > 3) {
      this.isLoading=true;
      this.people$ = null;
      this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm).subscribe(
        res={
    --->  this.people$ =res;
    --->  this.isLoading=false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
people$: Observable<IMerchant[]>;

fetchUsers($event) {
    let searchTerm = $event.term;
    if (searchTerm.length > 3) {
      this.isLoading=true;
      this.people$ = null;
      this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm);
      this.isLoading=false;
    }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
getMerchantProfile(id){
    var options = this.getOptions();
    return this.http.get<IMerchant[]>(environment.APIBaseURL+"/getMerchantProfile/"+id,options);
}
```

merchant.model.ts

```
export interface IMerchant{
    email:String,
    mobile : String,
    password: String,
    businessName : String,
    otp:Number,
    info:string,
    url:String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i prefer using the teardown method `.add()`. it doesn't pollute your pipe chain of data manipulation and is also executed after an error is handled:

```
this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm)
    .pipe(
        // manipulate data here
    )
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            // handle final data
        },
        error => {
            // handle error
        }
    ).add(() => {
        // teardown here (e.g. this.isLoading=false;)
    });
```

By the way: if `this.people$` is an observable, you can not assign it inside the subscribe callback. you'll need to assign it to the response of the userService method you are using. Be careful not to call subscribe on the stream since it will return you a subscription instead of an observable:

```
this.people$ = this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm).pipe(...)
```

Comment: As @Argee suggested I get an error...guess it is because of subscribe  
`Type 'IMerchant[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<IMerchant[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.ts(2740)
`
Using the below did the task..  
`this.people$ = this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm).pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading=false))`

Thanks too @aravind @jordi for showing me the pipe and finalize function

Answer (score 1):

You can actually `pipe` it and add a `finalize`

```
this.userService.getMerchantsBySearch(searchTerm)
.pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading=false))
.subscribe(
    res => {
         this.people$ =res;
    });
```